# Using Coil library - imageView.draw(canvas) - Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, coil

This occur when try to draw canvas from imageView which using Coil to load image.

Could you help me solve problem? Thank you all

```
 fun loadImageFromUrl() {
        bodyImageView?.load(imagePathServer)
    }
```

This is code for draw bitmap from imageview

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View?): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(view!!.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        var canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        view.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
```

Problem is shown

[image: l]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I found a way to solve problem that just add `allowHardware(false)` in side load image and it worked. This is [description](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/recipes/#shared-element-transitions) why crash happed.

```
   bodyImageView?.load(imagePathServer) {
            allowHardware(false)
        }
```